# compare user supplied list against table, with nulls for non-matching rows

Tags: sql, db2

Given a list of user-supplied numbers, which I'll refer to as `myList`, I want to find out which ones have a match against table `MasterList`, and which ones are null (no match)

so, given db contents

```
MasterList
----------

ID    Number
1     3333333
2     4444444
3     5555555
```

If `myList` is  `['1111111','2222222','3333333','4444444']`

I want the following output:

```
1111111, null
2222222, null
3333333, 1
4444444, 2
```

---

#### Ideas I've tried:

This, of course, yields only the ones that match.

```
select Number, ID
from MasterList
where Number in('1111111','2222222','3333333','4444444')
```

My next idea is no more helpful:

```
select temp.Number, master.Number
from MasterList master 
left join MasterList temp 
    on master.id=temp.id 
       and temp.Number in('1111111','2222222','3333333','4444444')
```

If the list were itself a table `temp`, it would be trivial to get the desired output:

```
select temp.number, master.id 
from temp    -- (ie, the list, where temp.number is the given list)
left join master on master.number=temp.number
-- optional where
where temp.number in('1111111','2222222','3333333','4444444')
```

This idea never materialized:

```
select temp.number, master.id
from (select '1111111','2222222','3333333','4444444') temp
left join master on master.number on....
```

Can this be done without a temporary table?

If not, how do you make a temporary table in ***DB2***?  (IBM documentation is helpful if you already know how to do it...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want an outer join, here a left outer join (we want all the rows from the left and any rows on the right that match the join condition), as you rightly say in the question. Here I'm using a Common Table Expression (CTE) to basically create a temp table on the fly.

```
WITH inlist (num) as ( VALUES 
  (111111),
  (222222),
  (333333),
  (444444) )
SELECT num, id 
FROM inlist LEFT OUTER JOIN masterlist
    ON masterlist.number = inlist.num
ORDER BY num;
```

That yields:

```
NUM         ID         
----------- -----------  
     111111           -  
     222222           -  
     333333           1  
     444444           2  

  4 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: Nice - I didn't know DB2 had WITH.

Comment: beautiful, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: In case you don't like CTEs for some reason you can also use the TABLE function in the FROM clause:

select num, id from inlist left outer join TABLE(values (111111), (222222)) as inlist ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super-familiar with DB2 (haven't written SQL for that in at least 15 years, and not much back then), so I don't know how much you'll need to edit this to make it work, but I think this will do what you want **(Edited SQL to use VALUES clause)**:

```
SELECT 
    my.Number1,
    CASE WHEN ml.Number1 IS NULL
    THEN NULL
    ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY my.Number1) END AS Indicator
FROM 
    (VALUES ('1111111'),('2222222'),('3333333'),('4444444')) 
    AS my(Number1)
LEFT JOIN
    MasterList AS ml
ON
    my.Number1 = ml.Number1;
```

Comment: This would be tied to the duration of some sort of session, rather than just for the duration of the query, wouldn't it?  That seems like a lot of overhead for a single query.  (In my mind, I'm contrasting that to a subquery, which in effect makes a temporary table).  If I have further queries, do I have to delete from the table first?

Comment: I just edited this to use the VALUES clause to input your list of numbers, I think this makes it pretty clean for you.

Comment: I’ll have to give that a try. That looks very straightforward.  I already accepted the other answer, but if this works too I’ll vote your answer up.  Thanks.